# Calculating SUM based on several conditions and creating new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

here is an excerpt of my dataframe `df` (many more countries and years in full dataframe)

```
   country.x    year     emissions      etsemit
   Austria      2005     16194772.5     16539659
   Austria      2005     15039192.4     15275065
   Austria      2005     13757090.8     14124646
   Austria      2005     13582006.8     14572511
   Austria      2009     12526267.6     12767555
   Austria      2010     13852187.5     15506112
   Austria      2011     13666544.9     15131551
   Austria      2012     12256272.5     13121434
   Austria      2012     11224625.0      8074514
   Austria      2012      9499543.9      6426135
   Austria      2015     10623549.8      7514263
   Austria      2016     10448925.8      7142937
   Belgium      2005     29246990.2     25460856
   Belgium      2006     28136794.9     24099282
   Belgium      2007     27435552.7     23706084
   Belgium      2009     25344134.8     23166180
   Belgium      2009     25744709.0     21185552
   Belgium      2009     26341043.0     22073616
   Belgium      2011     22921875.0     18950876
   Belgium      2012     22809482.4     17463388
   Belgium      2013     21242431.6     16728267
   Belgium      2013     20375966.8     15230243
   Belgium      2013     21091058.6     16053800
   Belgium      2016     19792162.1     15027777
```

I want to get the sums of `emissions` for each `country.x` and `year`. The results should be fed into a new dataframe which should like this:

```
   country.x    year     emissions      
   Austria      2005     value of calculation SUM     
   Austria      2009     value of calculation SUM 
   Austria      2010     value of calculation SUM 
   Austria      2011     value of calculation SUM 
   Austria      2012     value of calculation SUM 
   Austria      2015     value of calculation SUM 
   Austria      2016     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2005     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2006     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2007     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2009     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2011     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2012     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2013     value of calculation SUM 
   Belgium      2016     value of calculation SUM
```

I'm struggling with creating the sums based on `x.country` and `year. I guess that's a pretty easy one, but please excuse me question.

Thanks for any type of help.

Nordsee

Comment: Don't you just need `aggregate(emissions~country.x + year , df, sum)` ? or anything from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R:

```
aggregate(emissions~country.x + year , df, sum)
```

dplyr:

```
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(country.x, year) %>% summarise(emissions_sum = sum(emissions))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Very appreciated.